# AWS Lambda php: Where to put the php.ini

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create a php 7.3.6 layer for AWS Lambda on the basis of the stackery layer. [ [see here](https://github.com/stackery/php-lambda-layer) ]

I try to make mySQL usable by adding  adding `mysqli.so`, `pdo_mysql.so` and `mysqlnd.so` into the modules folder and making an entry into php.ini.

The layer per se will work fine, but it won't load the mySQL extension. 
If I create a simple lambda function consisting only of `phpinfo()` this will tell me, that my ini file was not found and that it is expected to be in `/etc`.

Output of phpinfo():

```
System  Linux 169.254.201.229 4.14.114-93.126.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May     8 20:42:46 UTC 2019 x86_64
Build Date  May 28 2019 15:55:44
Server API  Built-in HTTP server
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /opt/etc/php-7.3.d/:/var/task/php-7.3.d/
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20180731
PHP Extension   20180731
Zend Extension  320180731
Zend Extension Build    API320180731,NTS
PHP Extension Build     API20180731,NTS
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    enabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  available, disabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
[...]
```

The folder structure of the .zip file I use for the php-layer is as follows:

```
bootstrap
php.ini
bin
| php
lib 
| [...]
| php
| 7.3
| | modules
| | | [...]
```

Do I have to change my folder structure, or can I tell php where to search for the `php.ini`?

Comment: php.ini must be in the same dir as your php, so in in etc/ you will find the php dir.

Comment: That could be just what I needed to solve this.

In the original bootstrap file php is beeing started with -c "php.ini location" - but that location was incorrect. Now I started it with the correct location (wich is "/opt/" when php.ini resiedes in the same folder as bootstrap).

This could have fixed it. phpinfo() gives a proper response, but another php file times out now. 

I'll investigate if this is a different problem or caused by the ini-file.
Thanks a lot by the way. That was a good push to the right direction.

Comment: I have put the php.ini in the root of my lambda.  I have set it to the correct extension_dir.  I have set it to load extension=mysqli.so  My phpinfo shows that it knows the correct extension_dir.  I have listed all the *.so files.  However, I still receive "Class 'mysqli' not found".  get_loaded_extensions() shows that mysqlnd is loaded.  But if I try to use it I get 'mysqlnd' not found.  If you know the solution, please let me know.

Comment: https://github.com/stackery/php-lambda-layer/issues/40
This is how I solved it, when I ran into the problem.